# android how to handle button send on send email activity

Tags: android

```
private void sendImage(String fileName,String toUser){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("jpeg/image");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {toUser});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
    "Test Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
    "go on read the emails"); 
    File downloadedPic =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileName + ".jpg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

i have some problem with handle the sending email. i mean that after i have sent the email to the user i will finish the activity and reference to the previous activity. but i don't want that. i want after i send the email to the user i will reference to the next activity. how could i do this? please help ! thank you...

Answer (score 0):

you can override OnActivityResult Method in your activity.

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Intent intentobj=new  Intent(currentclassname.this,nextactivity.class)
          startActivity(intentobj);
          finish();

            }


        }
}
```

I think this helps you.

Comment: Dear deepa when the user click on send on my current activity it doesn't = result_ok .. the result is the other...